# How to make a URL as a book mark in android?

Tags: android

Anyone knows please help me,How to make a URL as a book mark in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Browser.SaveBookMark()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#saveBookmark%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) , But it sometimes gives an exception.